# TypeError: "Unsupported operand types: string * float"

Tags: php

I have the Error: `TypeError Unsupported operand types: string * float`
The Error is in this Line:
`$pricere1 = $db_price * $validate->getIntervalFactor($runtime) * $mainrabatt_script;`
I tried to find the Error but nothing worked for me :/

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: I have the PHP Version 8.0.15

Comment: Did you `var_dump()` each variables to see the values ? I guess one of them is not a number. See a simple example : https://3v4l.org/cNWGI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are multiplying `string` with `float`. One of your variable is holding `string` value.
You can `var_dump()` to see which variable hold the string data, and change the value to float. Otherwise you can cast those variable to `float`.

```
$pricere1 = (float)$db_price * (float)$validate->getIntervalFactor($runtime) * (float)$mainrabatt_script;
```

Comment: Anisur, try running `"3.14" * "3.14"` you will see that PHP successfully converts the strings into float. So, the problem the asker has that he/she has some strings that PHP cannot convert to float.

Comment: Thanks! Now i castet everything and it worked!

Comment: I just discovered in the AMP plugin for WP in 3 files multiplication of float with const (actually float), but it was failing as recognized float * string 8-/ with PHP 8.1 installed on server

Answer (score 0):

One or more of the following is a `String`:

- `$db_price`
- `$validate->getIntervalFactor($runtime)`
- `$mainrabatt_script`

When trying to multiply values, if PHP finds a `String`, then it will try to convert it into a numeric value. However, some `String` values are not numeric. I believe that `$mainbratt_script` is not numeric and PHP fails to convert it.

To solve your issue, make sure that you only multiply numeric values.