# How to debug 'TypeError thrown - Unsupported operand types: string / float' in Wordpress | when upgradet to PHP 8.1

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

As I'm not an experienced PHP / Wordpress developer, I hope one of you could point me in the right direction.

It's a complete custom theme which runs fine on php 7.4, but when I upgrade the php version to 8.0 or 8.1, the site breaks. Only the navigation is still working and in the body it's showing:

**TypeError thrown - Unsupported operand types: string / float**

I did a little research and found that it has to do with mixed variable types and how to solve it.
Unfortunately I don't have a clue which variable(s) are causing this.

I tried disabling all of the plugins, which gave me the same result, so the problem must be in the theme itself.

The last thing I tried was pasting every theme related code in this linting tool:
https://phpcodechecker.com/

That didn't give me any clue also.

I hope anyone could give me a solution to detect the cause, because our hosting partner stops supporting php 7.4 soon.

Answer (score -1):

You can allways cast variables before using them.

Before:

```
$a = '10' / 5.5;
$a = $b/$c;
$a = strlen(12345);
```

After:

```
$a = (float)'10' / 5.5;
$a = (int)$b/(int)$c;
$a = strlen((string)12345);
```

Look in detail here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Also answered here:
[TypeError: "Unsupported operand types: string * float"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71064315/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-string-float)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but that's also the problem. I don't know which variable (of the hundreds of them) to look for. So it's not about how to solve the issue, but about how to find the variables that cause this problem. The error message doesn't give any clues where to look.